# Why does the compiler not find a type in this class even though it is forward declared?

Tags: c++, header-files, shared-ptr

I have two classes `Edge` and `Line` which represent respectively an edge between nodes on a graph and a line associated to that edge which in the context of my programme is an object which acts as a visual representation of the edge and is used to draw the 'edge' using a GUI library. I am trying to find a way to link these two objects in my code by means of a pointers from `Edge` to `Line` and `Line` to `Edge` which will be stored on those objects. I want to do this so that I can run some algorithm on `Edge` objects. Each `Line` object corresponding to an `Edge` has some properties such as colour, thickness etc which are drawn by a GUI plotting library.

An example usage:

```
Edge e = Edge(); //create an edge
Line l = Line(e); //create a line and pass it the edge
```

Where the created `edge` object is passed by reference into the constructor of `Line` which then sets a pointer to this edge and also sets a pointer on Edge to this Line such that the Edge and Line have some 'knowledge' of each other:

```
Line::Line(Edge& e)
{
    corresponding_edge_ = make_shared<Edge>(e);
    e.setLine(make_shared<Line>(this));
};
```

The relevant parts of my `Edge` class looks like this:

The `edge.h` file:

```
//===== Edge.h =====

#pragma once
#include <memory>

using namespace std; 

class Line;

class Edge {
private:
    weak_ptr<Line> associated_line_;
public:
    Edge();
    ~Edge();
    void setLine(shared_ptr<Line> l);
    weak_ptr<Line> Line();
```

The `edge.cpp` file:

```
//===== Edge.cpp =====

using namespace std; 

Edge::Edge(){};

Edge::~Edge() {};

void Edge::setLine(shared_ptr<Line> l) {
    associated_line_ = l;
}

weak_ptr<Line> Edge::Line() {
    return associated_line_;
};
```

The relevant parts of my `Line` class looks like this:

The `line.h` file:

```
//===== Line.h =====

#pragma once 
#include <memory>
#include "edge.h"

using namespace std;

class Edge;

class Line {
    private:
        weak_ptr<Edge> corresponding_edge_;
    public:
        Line();
        Line(Edge& e);
        ~Line();
};
```

The `line.cpp` file:

```
//===== Line.cpp =====

#include "line.h"
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

Line::Line() {};

Line::Line(Edge& e)
{
    corresponding_edge_ = make_shared<Edge>(e);
    e.setLine(make_shared<Line>(this));
};

Line::~Line() {};
```

I have made sure to only include `edge.h` in the `line.h` header and to forward declare `Line` in `edge.h` to avoid a circular reference. However when I compile this code I get the following error:

`` std::shared_ptr`:`Edge::Line` is not a valid template type argument for parameter `_Ty ``

Why does this class try to find the type of `Line` on the `Edge` class rather than from the definition in `Line.h`?

Comment: In order to create an Edge, it needs to be able to see it's full definition. Inside the cpp files, include the appropriate headers.

Comment: On another note, `using namespace std` in a header is a terrible idea.

Comment: `#include` is a [preprocessor directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) that copies the text in the header and replaces the line `#include <your_header>`. Once the `using namespace std;` statement is declared in a file, it cannot be excluded for any source files that include that file.

Comment: `weak_ptr<Line> Line();` in `Edge` declares a member function `Line`, which hides the type of the same name. This member function is not a valid template argument.

Comment: Declaring new shared_ptrs in this way does not do what you think it does

Comment: @MooingDuck Am I correct in saying that calling the constructor make_shared is going to allocate new memory? I should rather use the constructor shared_ptr() and pass in the instance I want to make a shared_ptr to?

Comment: `make_shared(e)` will make a new shared object that is a *copy* of `e`, and therefore no `Line` objects ever have `corresponding_edge_` that is the same as any other `Line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new here and I hope I don't get many warnings...

The answer for the question is that what @ChrisMM commented: you should add the include headers to the cpp files:

```
#include "line.h"
#include "edge.h"
```

> Why does this class try to find the type of Line on the Edge class rather than from the definition in Line.h?

Once there is no full declaration, the compiler only knows the class name, not the full definition. This implies you cannot access any member or the type size.

All those weak_ptr and shared_ptr are all template instantiations. When the template gets instantiated inside functions/methods, this often causes the full definition to become required.

I have found few other problems in your code:
When you declare:

```
weak_ptr<Line> Line();
```

Causes ambiguity. Apparently, *the compiler thinks you wish to create an Edge to Line conversion*. **Edit:** Actually, the member function name shadows the type name (thanks to @Davis Herring). This causes the compiler to use the Line member function as a template argument (thanks to @molbdnilo).
Just renaming it to:

```
weak_ptr<Line> getLine();
```

Fixed this and removed ambiguity.

**Edit:** Instead, some may prefer to use **class** before Line whenever the template is instantiated, example:

```
weak_ptr<class Line> Line();
```

Also,

```
e.setLine(make_shared<Line>(this));
```

Does not seem to work, as make_shared expects the object not the pointer.
However, this should work:

```
e.setLine(make_shared<Line>(*this));
```

**Edit:** However, this is a bad idea... as the *this* pointer may not be adequate to be shared depending on how the object is allocated or deallocated: it might cause double deletions. Instead, you should make Line inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this:

```
class Line : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Line>
```

And use the following instead of make_shared for this case:

```
 e.setLine(this->shared_from_this());
```

Also, the edge.h is missing the class termination, but I guess that problem was just in the question.
After these changes I managed to compile it.

Anyway... Template instantiations often cause ridiculous amount of errors and warnings that often causes confusion, even to the best of us!
Best wishes!

Comment: There’s no (putative) “Edge to Line conversion”, but the member function name shadows the type name, and it’s IFNDR to do that after having already used the outer name like that.  (You can qualify the type name to avoid the collision.)

Comment: @Gottardi thanks for taking the time to answer, much appreciated! Now that I see it, it is quite obvious. I'll be sure to go with a better naming convention of `getMember()` in future to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: No problem, I also want to notify that added a few new improvements to my answer. Also, this is my first accept. Thank you as well!